# Restaurar DB con parametros desde Batch (.bat)

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedure, batch

tengo una pequeña duda en Sql y quisiera saber si alguno de uds me puede ayudar. Tengo el siguiente SP:

```
Create Procedure Es.StackOverflow

@NombreDB varchar(6),
@Ruta varchar(max)

AS BEGIN

RESTORE DATABASE @NombreDB 
    FROM DISK='@Ruta';
END 
---por colocar un ejemplo
```

Mi idea es ejecutar dicho procedimiento a través de un .bat o un  Batch, pero no sé como enviar esos parámetros desde mi ".bat" a mi SP (Procedimiento Almacenado) y siendo exactos, tampoco de el C# a el Batch. (aunque he leído sobre el process)
¿No sé si me puedan dar una guía o recomendación ante lo que planteo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para ejecutar un SP desde algún BATCH / BAT puedes utilizar [SQLCMD](https://docs.microsoft.com/ES-ES/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

Ejemplo

```
sqlcmd -Q "exec Es.StackOverflow 'NOMBRE_BD','RUTA' " -S SERVIDOR -d BASE_DE_DATOS
```

Comment: Con eso de: 'NOMBRE_BD','RUTA' se enviarían los parámetros al script, no?

Comment: @OtroBrayan si, esos son los parametros dentro de las comillas dobles.

Comment: una ultima pregunta, esos parámetros en el Batch los defino como? 
bastaría con un "%1"?

Comment: @OtroBrayan exacto.